# How to set Diffrent value then 'auto' in connection.release_mode (spring + hibernate)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, connection, isolation-level

Is it possible to set a diffrent value then 'auto' to the hibernate propery - "connection.release_mode"?

We use Spring with hibernate, When I try to define in this propery - 'after_transaction' (When i define hibernate properties in session factory definition), In runtime i get an exception (Spring exception) that the only valid value (in Spring terms) for this prop is 'on_close'. This fact cause us many troubles. We use the session-per-request pattern (meaning " a client sends a request to the server, where the Hibernate persistence layer is running. Hibernate opens a new Session, and all database operations are executed in this unit of work."([hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#session-per-operation)  ). when   on_close is defined - connection is being allocate per service (there is not re-use of connections).

We use HibernateTransactionManager to manage transactions in combination with TransactionInterceptor. We handle sessions with AnnotationSessionFactoryBean (our session factory) , I try to define in the session factory decleration in the "hibernateProperties" part - > connection.release_mode=after_transaction. In Runtime when server try loading session factory I got this exception :

```
org.springframework.transaction.InvalidIsolationLevelException: HibernateTransactionManager is not allowed to support custom isolation levels: make sure that its 'prepareConnection' flag is on (the default) and that the Hibernate connection release mode is set to 'on_close' (SpringTransactionFactory's default). Make sure that your LocalSessionFactoryBean actually uses SpringTransactionFactory: Your Hibernate properties should *not* include a 'hibernate.transaction.factory_class' property!
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:515)
    ... 121 more
```

Why spring do that? and is there a bypass

any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more details like - How are you obtaining a session? How are you managing your transactions? Add some sample code. That may help us in identifying the problem.

Comment: Are you overriding any transaction isolation levels in your code? Are you using a connection pool? Could you post a sample business method and your sessionFactory configuration code? Also how do you obtain a hibernate session? Do you use sessionFactory.openSession() or sessionFactory.getCurrentSession or have spring inject your session or use hibernateTemplate.getSession?

Answer (score 1):

To set different connection release mode you have to create a file

`src/main/resources/hibernate.properties`

and set the value

`hibernate.connection.release_mode=AFTER_STATEMENT`

Other available values can be found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/transactions-connection-release.html)